# ADF input variables monitoring

Tags: azure-data-factory, grafana

I have an Azure Data Factory (ADF) where I run a master pipeline that invokes sub-pipelines using an input parameter. The sub-pipeline queries a table, and the table name is passed as an input parameter. I'm facing an issue with error logging when executing the master pipeline because I can't easily see which parameter was used in this run in the "Monitor -> Trigger Runs" section (of course, I can go to the Parameters section, but it's cumbersome with a large number of tables). Is there a way to display pipeline names in the "Monitor -> Trigger Runs" section to show something like "pipelineName_inputVariable" instead of just "pipelineName" every time? Additionally, I have Grafana configured with Prometheus and Azure Monitor, but I haven't found any metrics where I could monitor input parameters of the pipelines. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK dynamic naming of pipelines in ADF is not possible.

You might want to look into logging; if you activate all logs in azure datafactory diagnostic settings you can query them and create an overview of pipeline runs and the parameters used to trigger them.

I've written a simple query that lists all recent pipeline runs and retrieves some relevant dynamic pipeline parameter ('Parameter_input_s') that is set in the subpipeline:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where * contains 'factory'
| where OperationName ==  "pipeline2 - Succeeded"
| project Parameters_input_s, TimeGenerated, OperationName
```

- example pipeline
  [image: Example of a pipeline calling a pipeline using a pipeline parameter]
- location of ADF parameters setting which you are trying to make easier
  [image: Parameter location in ADF]

[image: Parameter location in ADF]

- diagnostic settings
  [image: How to add diagnostic settings in portal]
- query results
  [image: Example of results from the query]

(alternative-1: You can retrieve pipeline names and variables inside of other pipelines, which would allow you to construct a 'pipelines pipeline' that reads out information from other pipelines and creates an overview of which pipelines have run with which parameters, but this seems overengineering.)

(alternative-2: you could also use another trigger outside of Azure Datafactory: for example github actions allow dynamic names for pipelines and you could transfer your master pipelines to github actions and have your overview there. In general once things get slightly complex low-code tools like ADF might not be the best fit).